# Rate Limit Issue, looping through dynamic Promise requests

Tags: javascript, loops, promise, async-await, rate-limiting

I'm having an issue with rate limit 429 when sending to many requests to an api. I'm using the api's Node.js library to make the requests with Javascript es-6 Promises.

Each Promise takes two arguments, and the arguments change on each request.

I have solved the rate limit issue by chaining promises with .then() and including a delay function that returns a resolved promise after ??ms.

```
let delay = (time = delay_ms) => (result) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(result), time));
```

Something like this:

`request(arg1, arg2)
.then(delay(300))
.then(request(arg1, arg2))
.then(delay(300))...`

This solved the rate limit issue BUT it's created a real headache with the amount of code I'm having to write using that solution because I'll have to write an awful amount of code.

I would like `arg1` and `arg2` to live in separate arrays so I can iterate through them to dynamically build the promise request and include a delay between each request.

I attempted to iterate with a forEach and for loop but the request all fire within milliseconds of each other creating the rate limit 429 issue again.

Is there a solution where:

- ALL `arg1` can be stored in an array `let arr1 = ['USD', 'EUR' ...]`
- ALL `arg2` can be stored in an array `let arr2 = [60, 300, 600 ...]`
- Where I can dynamically create the Promise request using `arr1` & `arr2` with a `delay()` in between each request?

my code looks something like this:

```
requestPromise(arg1_a, arg2_a).then(res => delay(ms)).then(requestPromise(arg1_b, arg2_b)).then(res => delay(ms))...
```

Any help in maybe async await? I've tried but I can't seem to get it to work with this problem? maybe due to Promises and dynamic arguments??? Not sure I'm understanding how to incorporate async await with a dynamic Promise and iteration etc...

Any help appreciated.

Comment: [`Promises Async`](https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8), `CTRL-F` -> `Pitfall 4: Gotta remember to handle errors`. Read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I properly understand what you're looking for, you want to iterate through your arrays with a delay between each request, calling `requestPromise(x, y)` where `x` and `y` come from each of the arrays.

You can do that like this:

```
const delay_ms = 100;

function delay(t = delay_ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    });
}

function iterate(a1, a2, t) {
    let index = 0;
    const len = Math.min(a1.length, a2.length);
    if (len === 0) {
        return Promise.reject(new Error("iterate(a1, a2, t) needs two non-zero length arrays"));
    }

    function run() {
        return requestPromise(a1[index], a2[index]).then(() => {
            index++;
            // if still more to process, insert delay before next request
            if (index < len) {
                return delay(t).then(run);
            }
        });
    }

    return run();
}

// sample usage
let arr1 = ['USD', 'EUR' ...];
let arr2 = [60, 300, 600 ...];

iterate(arr1, arr2, 500).then(() => {
    // all done here
}).catch(err => {
    // got error here
});
```

This works by creating a promise chain where each new request is chained onto the previous promise chain and executed only after the delay.  The arrays are accessed via an `index` variable that is initialized to `0` and then incremented after each iteration.

This function requires two non-zero length arrays and will iterate to the length of the shorter of the two arrays (if for some reason they aren't equal length).

Answer (score 0):

`Promises.all()` can be used for handling the returns from promises made by asynchronous calls however in order to handle the number of requests made concurrently the http.request code needs to limit the number of calls. Setting the `https.globalAgent.maxSocket = 20` has worked for me as a simple work around. This is obviously used when the requests are made a node client.

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty simple using `async/await` and a standard for loop.

```
async function iterate(arr1, arr2) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        await requestPromise(arr1[i], arr2[i]);
        await delay(300);
    }
}

let arr1 = ['USD', 'EUR'];
let arr2 = [60, 300, 600];
iterate(arr1, arr2);
```

This implementation assumes that the arrays are of the same length.